# Including latest jquery makes the page stop working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on the site where an old version of `jQuery` is included `(1.7.2)` in the header.

Since the plugin I need to use requires latest version, I started by linking the latest version `(2.1.3)` in the footer, but just by linking it, some of the features on site stopped working.

I know that if I used any scripts after it that I should use noConflict, but this happens even if I only add

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

What can i do to make this stop?

Comment: noConflict is if you use two versions of jQuery symultaneously

Comment: *"What can i do to make this stop?"* don't include the latest version. You should only upgrade to the latest version if either 1: you want to use a plugin that doesn't support your older version, or 2: you have updated your existing code/plugins to support the new version. In the case of #1, you must use noConflict properly.

Comment: if i try to add $.noConflict(); before including the latest version, nothing happens, and some of the features on the page still dont work

Answer (score 0):

The semantic versioning specifies as major.minor.patch (1.0.1) syntax.
from semver.org

increment the:

- MAJOR version when you make incompatible API changes,
- MINOR version when you add functionality in a backwards-compatible manner, and
- PATCH version when you make backwards-compatible bug fixes.

So in your case you are upgrading to non backward compatible version, and some of your page functions might be using old APIs, so its causing the problem.

Use noConflict for new version and provide that variable to your plugin.